# SQL Date and Recent Entry Records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a datetime field "Insurance_Start_Date" in TableA and I need the following qualifications to be added in to the query.

1. Get all the records starting April 1st of previous year. Example: Insurance_Start_Date >= 2017-04-01. But I don't want the value to be hardcoded.
2. If a same member has 2 entries with different Insurance_Start_Date. Then I want to see only the recent record in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable...

```
declare @startDate datetime = cast(datepart(year,dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) as char(4)) + '0401'

select...from...where Insurance_Start_Date >= @startDate
```

For the second question, you can used a window function...

```
;with cte as(
select *, RN = row_number() over (partition by memberColumnID order by Insurance_Start_Date desc)
from YourTable
where Insurance_Start_Date >= @startDate)

select * from cte where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the 1st question. I cannot even use the 20170401 value. Because this is a Stored Procedure and I should provide a year logic, so whenever the SP gets executed on a given day, it will retrieve all the data from April 1st of PREVIOUS Year. Say, if the SP ran on 20190101. It should provide data >= 20180401.

Comment: Thanks for the update for Question 1. This is really helpful. I just tested and the results looks good. For Question 2, the provided logic looks perfect, but however I wanted to know if there would be any other way to implement it in the Stored Procedure, without manually doing select * from cte where RN = 1

Comment: @Bruce if you don't want the RN returned, just list out the columns you do want returned. This can also be handled by an inner join, but we'd need the table definition to code that

Comment: Got it. This makes sense. Thanks a lot for your inputs :)

Comment: I have a generic question. I have a field in the table as a varchar which holds date, example 20180517. Based on this field I want to add a condition to get only current year data. Example: field like '2018%'. Instead of using the like operator. I wanted to use a logic to get the data based on current year. What will be the effective way in doing it. Thanks!

Comment: where datepart(year,dateColumn) = datepart(year,getdate())